# I can't just add values to an array and then I want to print the values

Tags: c#

/*This is a simple code to add values to an array using c# and then just to print them. But I am having an error in order to do this. What possible error could be? */

```
        int size = 0, k = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter size of array: ");            
        size = Console.Read();
        string[] array = new string[size];  

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter at index: {0}", i);
            array[i] = Console.ReadLine();                
        }

        foreach (string s in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value at index: {0}", k++ + " = " + s);
        }
```

Comment: how is k supposed to increment in the second loop?

Comment: i have edited actual code now...having problem in first loop

Answer (score 2):

```
k++
```

in the foreach loop would work.

---

I would actually just write:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value at index: {0} = {1}", k++, s);
```

Comment: yea thats right...i forgot to add k++ while pasting here...having yet same problem

Comment: What error are you getting? And can you fix your code above to show what is actually being run then?

Comment: Your first loop keeps running because your `Console.Read()` call is setting the size to the ascii value of the input instead of the actual number(so 49 for '1', or 52 for '4' in your case).  You need to do a `Convert.ToUInt32(Colsole.ReadLine())` instead.

Comment: Exception problem after changing to [array[i] = Convert.ToUInt32(Colsole.ReadLine()).toString()]!...it says input string was not in correct format

Comment: size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
NOW it worked....thanks allot....u r the hero :)

Answer (score 0):

Twothings:

1)string[] array = new string[size];  likely to not compile, you can get a negative number

2) Console.WriteLine("Value at index: {0}", k + " = " + s);  -> should be i think Console.WriteLine("Value at index: {0}" + k + " = " + s);

Comment: The second part of your answer would not work, the `{0}` needs a parameter to be replaced with(after the comma) and is what the `k + " = " + s` would be

Comment: huh, then c# isnt that close to c/++ after all. its been some time since i learned c#.

Comment: It would be better to do Console.WriteLine("Value at index: {0} = {1}", k++, s); which I did but having same prob

Comment: maybe you should k++ outside of the writeline?

Comment: I wonder why my code put 52 in size as I am entering 4 in console

Comment: no I meant when this (size = Console.Read();) executes while debugging, I enter 4 for size in console but it enters 52....why?

Comment: ascii table. why dont you ReadLine()?

Comment: this seems to solve the ascii problem    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156363/console-readline-add-48-to-int     


Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: Exception problem now!...it says input string was not in correct format

Comment: yea it worked by Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); thanks allot

Comment: i will do, however, appreciate if you accept this answer, though you dont have to. if not mine, then pick any of the others, to mark this question has been answered.

Comment: you click on the 'v' sign next to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you could achieve what you want by changing the code within your foreach loop as shown below:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value at index {0}: {1}", k++, s);
```

(looks like Joe already has this solution in his answer as well).

`{0}` is a placeholder for the value of the first parameter to the Console.WriteLine method after the format string parameter.
`{1}` is a placeholder for the value of the second parameter to the Console.WriteLine method after the format string parameter.

I'm using `k++` to increment the value of `k` on each iteration of the foreach loop.

A foreach loop simply iterates over an `IEnumerable` object (or more specifically, an `IEnumerable<int>` object in this case), and the functionality of an `IEnumerable` object is that it simply gives you each item in the collection.  It has no concept of "index", so if you want to associate an index with each item, then you would need to take care of that yourself.

Note that for some collections, such as arrays and lists, you will always get the items in the order that they exist within those structures.  However, the `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces by themselves don't necessarily guarantee that you will get the items in any specific order, or that you will get the items in the same order if you loop over them a second time.  The order of iteration is determined by the underlying implementation, which is an array of integers (`int[]`) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think Console.Read() is causing you problems, try ReadLine() instead and convert to Int when necessary, and increment k:

```
 int size = 0, k = 0;
 Console.WriteLine("Enter size of array: ");
 size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
 string[] array = new string[size];

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter at index: {0}", i);
     array[i] = Console.ReadLine();
 }

 foreach (string s in array)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Value at index: {0}", k + " = " + s);
     k++;
 }

 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What do you mean? I put that last Console.ReadLine() in just to keep the console open so you can see the output. Does it do what you want if you take that out?

Comment: having problem now only in first loop...it keeps running on

Comment: Does it ask you to enter at index : x where x is more than you entered for the size of the array?

Comment: i.e. have you changed the size line to: size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Comment: size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); NOW it worked,,,thanks :)

Comment: There should be a tick mark next to top left of the answer, in between the up and down arrows. If you click that, it should go green.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `Console.Read()`? It reads *integers* corresponding to each of the characters in the input stream, but not until you press enter (which will in itself send two integers, one `13` and one `10`).

Maybe you should use `Console.ReadLine()` instead?

Comment: yea ryt...but loop keeps going on

Comment: I mean only the first loop

Comment: @Amir You still have `Console.Read()` in `size = Console.Read();`. What `size` do you think that gives you? It depends on the codepoint of the first character read from the input stream. Do you want the user to type in a number instead? At least you should write out `size` so the user can see what size he gets.

Answer (score 0):

This works (tested) :

```
        int size = 0, k = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter size of array: ");
        size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string[] array = new string[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter at index: {0}", i);
            array[i] =  Console.ReadLine();
        }

        foreach (string s in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value at index: {0} = {1}", k++, s);
        }

        Console.Read();
```